# Improving ts validation util functions for better types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've written this simple validation for n args that needs to be checked against null or undefined:

```
function validateInputs(...args: any[]) {
    return args.every((arg) => arg !== null && arg !== undefined);
}
```

Let's say that for example I pass into it an email and another value, both be `string | undefined`.

After checking for the return of this util functions I can be certain that those will surely be `string` and not `undefined`, but the ts compiler cannot get it. Is there a way that I can solve this other than using the **bang operator**?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this kind of narrowing using [predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function validateInputs<T>(args: (T | undefined | null)[]): args is T[] {
    return args.every((arg) => arg !== null && arg !== undefined);
}

function foo() {
    const inputs: (string | undefined)[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
    if(validateInputs(inputs)) {
        inputs // string[]
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYCSYADiFAM4A8AKgHwAUqATgObkBci91iAPouCx5gMMHix9EYEOnQBKANoBdOZ2ZtEMcomrLEAbwBQiE4iZ4oIJknXkAdHmR4mAT3qNWcxAF5aidYgAhN7eUjLoiABkkf6sQSECYEIiYlhyANyGAL6GhqCQsAiIwHBw9F5GpogQCORQmiRkHFx1TKIskoLCouKKSj6ICgDkJXBDADSIQwBGzENKmVUwwPRomDj4RKQU9KLb5HIVxlWme02IAPQXiK3tyscmOdlAA)